# was trying to sell a stock at a limit order of .83 i was passed by and never filled

Tags: stocks, selling

I was trading stocks today I put in a sell order with a limit of .83 I left the order and went to lunch I came back the order still wasn't filled and the price of the stock went up to .86.  I can't figure out why my stock would not sell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That should not be possible, but there can be all kind of issues. Exchanges closed at 1 pm today, was it too late? Did you use all-or-nothing? A typo in the limit? We need more info

Answer (score 2):

Saying that the stock went up to 86 cents is insufficient information. That  could have been the ask price which could be meaningless.

Suppose the current price is $0.81 x $0.86.  I buy some shares at 86 cents and that is the last trade.  You have placed an order to sell at 83 cents.  It would not be filled because the bid  is only 81 cents.

Another possibility is that you placed an All Or None order at 83 cents.  Th bid rose to 83 cents but there were not enough  shares were available at that price ($0.83 x $0.87) to fill your order so you got nothing because the bid then dropped.

Lastly, today was a 1/2 day of trading. Placing an order after after 1 PM would would not be transmitted if your broker requires that you have approval to trade during after hours and you do not have it.